# Chess game gui mouselisteners

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, mouse, chess

I'm a new programmer with limited experience. This is my first GUI design. I am trying to create a chess GUI with moving image icons and i will take mouse clicks on table's coordinates which are firstly and secondly pressed. But the problem is even if i define mouse listener methods ,which are originated from MouseListener interface, I can't get decent coordinates from mouse's movement. I have looked at MouseEvent object's getX and getY method's values and saw below:

```
mouseEntered (7,3)
mouseExited (3,77)
mouseEntered (3,15)
mouseExited (-1,55)
mouseEntered (61,55)
mouseExited (61,74)
mouseEntered (61,12)
mouseExited (63,33)
mouseEntered (1,33)
mouseExited (6,75)
mouseEntered (6,13)
mouseExited (18,68)
mouseEntered (18,6)
mouseExited (30,70)
mouseEntered (30,8)
mouseExited (62,43)
mouseEntered (0,43)
mouseExited (51,-5)
mouseEntered (51,57)
mouseExited (62,45)
mouseEntered (0,45)
mouseExited (63,17)
mouseEntered (1,17)
mouseExited (32,64)
mouseEntered (32,2)
mouseExited (61,64)
mouseEntered (61,2)
mouseExited (63,15)
mouseEntered (1,15)
mouseExited (-1,25)
mouseEntered (61,25)
mouseExited (-6,49)
mouseEntered (56,49)
mouseExited (-13,50)
mouseEntered (49,50)
mouseExited (-10,34)
mouseEntered (52,34)
mouseExited (8,-6)
mouseEntered (8,56)
mouseExited (1,-7)
mouseEntered (1,55)
mouseExited (13,-4)
mouseEntered (13,58)
mouseExited (57,-1)
mouseEntered (57,61)
mouseExited (62,59)
mouseEntered (0,59)
mouseExited (62,40)
mouseEntered (0,40)
mouseExited (33,-1)
mouseEntered (33,61)
mouseExited (-3,12)
mouseEntered (59,12)
mouseExited (28,-1)
mouseEntered (28,61)
mouseExited (-1,55)
mouseEntered (61,55)
mouseExited (-2,43)
mouseEntered (60,43)
mouseExited (-2,45)
mouseEntered (60,45)
mouseExited (9,62)
mouseEntered (9,0)
mouseExited (62,25)
mouseEntered (0,25)
mouseExited (64,42)
mouseEntered (2,42)
mouseExited (35,64)
mouseEntered (35,2)
mouseExited (62,50)
mouseEntered (0,50)
mouseExited (4,65)
mouseEntered (4,3)
mouseExited (21,63)
mouseEntered (21,1)
mouseExited (47,62)
mouseEntered (47,0)
mouseExited (65,6)
mouseEntered (3,6)
mouseExited (14,-13)
mouseEntered (14,49)
mouseExited (42,-17)
mouseEntered (42,45)
mouseExited (63,-2)
mouseEntered (1,60)
mouseExited (47,64)
mouseEntered (47,2)
mouseExited (63,24)
mouseEntered (1,24)
mouseExited (62,47)
mouseEntered (0,47)
mouseExited (65,24)
```

Although i have 8x8 grid layout, i am getting these coordinates. Why am i getting weird coordinates?

Moreover, I've tried to change image icons' location via mouse listeners. Because of getting weird coordinates I couldn't do anything. The code is below(without mouse listener methods):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    private Board auxBoard = new Board(); //8x8 String chess table class
    private JPanel[][] squares = new JPanel[8][8];
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8));
    private Container c;
    private String[][] chessBoard = auxBoard.strChessBoard; //invoke chess table on which game will be played

    private ImageIcon rookBlack = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/br.png");
    private ImageIcon rookWhite = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/wr.png");
    private ImageIcon bishopBlack = new ImageIcon(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/icons/bb.png");
    private ImageIcon bishopWhite = new ImageIcon(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/icons/wb.png");
    private ImageIcon knightBlack = new ImageIcon(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/icons/bkn.png");
    private ImageIcon knightWhite = new ImageIcon(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/icons/wkn.png");
    private ImageIcon kingBlack = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/bk.png");
    private ImageIcon kingWhite = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/wk.png");
    private ImageIcon queenBlack = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/bq.png");
    private ImageIcon queenWhite = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/wq.png");
    private ImageIcon pawnBlack = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/bp.png");
    private ImageIcon pawnWhite = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")
            + "/icons/wp.png");

    public GUI() {
        c = getContentPane();
        setBounds(100, 100, 510, 530);
        setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 204));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Tittle");
        setResizable(false);
        c.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.setBounds(3, 3, 500, 500);
        mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        c.add(mainPanel);
        this.drawChessBoard();
        this.arrangeChessPieces();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void drawChessBoard(){

        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
                squares[y][x] = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                squares[y][x].addMouseListener(this);
                mainPanel.add(squares[y][x]);

                if (y % 2 == 0)
                    if (x % 2 != 0)
                        squares[y][x].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    else
                        squares[y][x].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                else
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    squares[y][x].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                else
                    squares[y][x].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
    }

    private void arrangeChessPieces() {

        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                this.squares[y][x].add(
                        this.getPieceObject(chessBoard[y][x]),
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);
                this.squares[y][x].validate();
            }
    }

    private JLabel getPieceObject(String strPieceName) {

        JLabel lblTemp;

        if (strPieceName.equals("RB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.rookBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("BB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.bishopBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("NB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.knightBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("QB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.queenBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("KB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.kingBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("PB"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.pawnBlack);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("RW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.rookWhite);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("BW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.bishopWhite);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("NW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.knightWhite);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("QW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.queenWhite);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("KW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.kingWhite);
        else if (strPieceName.equals("PW"))
            lblTemp = new JLabel(this.pawnWhite);
        else
            lblTemp = new JLabel();

        return lblTemp;

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mousePressed (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mousePressed (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouseReleased (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouseEntered (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouseExited (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUI test = new GUI();
    }

}
```

How could i make these coordinates more easy to use? Also, how could i move chess pieces move on the table and get their first and last locations as x,y coordinates?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of MouseEvent.getY() yields:

> Returns the vertical y position of the event relative to the source component.

getX() and getY() do not have anything to do with your board squares but are returning a value in pixels. More precisely, the distance in y or x direction from the source.

EDIT: it seems you chose the individual squares to be panels. I would just assign a seperate Listener to each panel. So when an event is triggered, the corresponding listener can tell you that it was selected.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to have a `JPanel` that represents the Board GUI, and it has a member field that is an array of `JPanel`'s, each element being a tile of the board.  Then you can register events with each tile (which should know its coordinate), and not have to worry about translating mouse coordinates at all.

You can look at my chess game on github for reference, specifically:

https://github.com/amir650/chess/blob/master/code/com/chess/view/GuiTable.java